# Where did iOS Simulator go after Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I sometimes need to run iOS Simulator independent of Xcode to test on Safari. I used to be able to just look for it in Spotlight and run it from there. But ever since I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1, Spotlight can no longer find it. Any idea where it went?

Comment: @MDT That's a great idea! Mind putting it in the answer section?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Launch the simulator from Xcode and when it appears in your dock, right click it and select keep in dock.

The simulator can also be launched directly from Finder:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\
>   Simulator.app

Edit: I don't know if this has been here the whole time, but I just discovered that you can also launch the simulator by right clicking Xcode's icon in your dock >> Open Developer Tool >> iOS Simulator.

[image]

Comment: It's in Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/

Answer (score 2):

It's embedded in the `Xcode.app` bundle that you download from the Mac Store or the Developer website. The best way I've found to launch it now is to just launch some app and then kill the app but don't quit the simulator.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have been doing. But it's annoying to have to wait for Xcode + an app to launch to just test on Safari...I was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: @pixelfreak You can navigate to the app bundle in Finder, ctrl+click it, select `Show Bundle Contents` and then navigate to the simulator and launch it there too. Maybe drag a shortcut to it. The simulator is now buried under the Developer directory for the specific SDK, not in the top level Developer directory, under Applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the technical path to where the sim app now sits

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app

(Even though the display name when you look in finder is now changed to "iOS Simulator.app")

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can also install the Simulator by going to Xcode's `Preferences > Downloads`. After that, I presume the Simulator will be its own app like before.